# Bug in DayRange?

Tags: date-and-time

```
DayRange[DateObject[{2019, 1, 1}], 
 DateObject[{2019, 12, 31}], "Holiday", HolidayCalendar -> "Germany"]
```

Why is Oct 3 missing? It's German Unity Day since 1990. It's a public holiday, by law.

Comment: Maybe Wolfram just did'nt know...

Comment: It's missing a few Chinese holidays too.